# URL Rewriting, many "folders" to variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am rewriting some url on my website, and I get a problem with my second rewriting rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/(home|works|contact|service)$ /index.php?language=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When I try to reach this page, the page content is well-loaded, but the css is not. My stylesheet is in *resources/css/*, and when I go to a page like *website.net/en/works*, it is loaded from *en/resources/css*.

My others rewriting rules are the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)$ /index.php?language=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/(home|works|contact|service)$ /index.php?language=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/resume$ /resources/documents/$1/resume.pdf [L]
```

The first and last rules works fine, and I really don't understand why the second isn't working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show the html you are using exactly.  this seems like a relative url being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without the HTML you are using this is only a slightly educated guess.  As the css is being loaded from /en/resources/css you may want to check the url you are using for your css. If it is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css">
```

the it is loading correctly from /en/resources/css. to load from /resources/css the url needs to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css">
```

this will then force the load from /resources/css not /en/resources/css

that might be of help but like i said, only a guess without seeing the link tag in your html.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't thought it could come from the HTML. But you were right, this fixed my issue. Thanks!